# Parsing Categories,subcategories from a xml in a recursinve way and storing in db

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml where i have to parse the categories and store them in db.The categories have child categories and child categories have sub child categories.It is like tree structure.I need a recursive function to fetch the sub categories if a category have subcategory.I need to store categoryid,categoryname,parentcategoryid in db.

This is my xml

```
 <test>
    <categorylist>
    <categoryitem>
    <id>
    <![CDATA[ 47 ]]>
    </id>
    <name>
    <![CDATA[ Homeparties ]]>
    </name>
    </categoryitem>
    <categoryitem>
    <id>
    <![CDATA[ 86 ]]>
    </id>
    <name>
    <![CDATA[ All Products ]]>
    </name>
    </categoryitem>
    <categoryitem>
    <id>
    <![CDATA[ 111 ]]>
    </id>
    <name>
    <![CDATA[ Machines ]]>
    </name>
    <categorylist>
    <categoryitem>
    <id>
    <![CDATA[ 1147 ]]>
    </id>
    <name>
    <![CDATA[ Machine Colours ]]>
    </name>
    <categorylist>
    <categoryitem>
    <id>
    <![CDATA[ 1397 ]]>
    </id>
    <name>
    <![CDATA[ Black ]]>
    </name>
    </categoryitem>
    </categorylist>
    </categoryitem>
    </categorylist>
    </categoryitem>
    </categorylist>
    </test>
```

store them as 
category_id category_name parent_category_id

for the above i have tried like this.It is working fine for some levels like upto three levels.suppose if it is n levels,I need a recursive fuction.The below is my code.

```
if($xml){
                            $this->fetchCategoriesRecursive($xml);
}



      public function fetchCategoriesRecursive($categories)
      {
          foreach($categories->{'categorylist'}->{'categoryitem'} as $category)
                              {
                                    $this->insertCategory($category);

                                    foreach($category->{'categorylist'}->{'categoryitem'} as $category_child)
                                    {
                                          $this->insertCategory($category_child,$category->{'id'});

                                    foreach($category_child->{'categorylist'}->{'categoryitem'} as $category_sub_child)
                                    {
                                          $this->insertCategory($category_sub_child,$category_child->{'id'});

                                    }

                                    }
                              }
      }


public function insertCategory($category,$category_id)
      {
             $category_info=array();
             $category_info = $this->_db->fetchCol("SELECT category_id FROM category_mapping");

            $data = array();
            $data['category_id'] = $category->{'id'};
            $data['category_name'] = $category->{'name'};
                $data['parent_category_id'] = $category_id;

        if(!in_array($data['category_id'],$category_info))
        {
            $this->_db->insert('category_mapping', $data);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is no need for a recursion, you can iterate over all `categoryitem` elements using Xpath. Each node knows its position inside the DOM. So you can fetch all `categoryitem` parent elements and use the nearest (the first) one.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// iterate all categoryitem elements
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//categoryitem') as $node) {
  var_dump(
    [
      // fetch the id of the nearest categoryitem element on the ancestor axis
      'parent_id' => $xpath->evaluate('string(ancestor::categoryitem[1]/id)', $node),
      // fetch the id as string
      'id' => $xpath->evaluate('string(id)', $node),
      // fetch the name as string
      'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $node),
    ]
  );
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["parent_id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["id"]=>
  string(4) " 47 "
  ["name"]=>
  string(13) " Homeparties "
}
array(3) {
  ["parent_id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["id"]=>
  string(4) " 86 "
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) " All Products "
}
array(3) {
  ["parent_id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["id"]=>
  string(5) " 111 "
  ["name"]=>
  string(10) " Machines "
}
array(3) {
  ["parent_id"]=>
  string(5) " 111 "
  ["id"]=>
  string(6) " 1147 "
  ["name"]=>
  string(17) " Machine Colours "
}
array(3) {
  ["parent_id"]=>
  string(6) " 1147 "
  ["id"]=>
  string(6) " 1397 "
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) " Black "
}
```